# Scala Slick 3.0 Limit joined table

Tags: scala, slick

I have tables `CATEGORY` and `QUESTIONS` with category_id foreign_key
I need to take 3 categories and 3 questions from this categories.
How can I do it using slick 3.0.3?

P.S. Or, how to do it in mysql query

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way .

I assumed that your requirement is to fetch first 3 categories , and get one question for each category respectively.

```
val q = for {
          categories <- Tables.categories.take(3)
          groupedByCat <- Tables.questions.filter(_.catId === categories.id).groupBy(_.catId).map(_._1)
          questions<- Tables.questions.filter(_.catId === groupedByCat)
        } yield questions
```

Comment: What is most effiecient way to make 3 questions in each?